# ¿Como puedo generar una imagen a partir de un conjunto de otras(collage)?

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

¡Hola a todos!
Realice el esquema de un collage como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual muestra las imágenes correctamente, el punto es que me interesa guardar ese conjunto de imageViews en una sola imagen para su mejor manejo, pero no veo la forma de realizarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de unos días pude resolver mi problemática satisfactoriamente.
Les comparto lo que encontré:

Para crear un recurso bitmap a partir de algún elemento ya definido desde el xml, basta con colocar:

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

***view es el elemento que se convertira a imagen**

Mi problema fue que el collage se llenaba dinámicamente cada vez que accedieran a la ventana, por lo tanto el código anterior no me sirvió, sin embargo encontré una alternativa:

En este caso el layout **photobooks_05_collage** era lo que tenía el contenido de mi vista (collage)
Bastó con agregar al inicio un Layout que tendrá la función de contenedor, con propiedades ajustables al contenido:

```
    RelativeLayout viewRoot = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photobooks_05_collage, viewRoot, true);
    viewRoot.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //Aquí hice la logica y asignación de imagenes al collage, poblando cada ImageView correspondiente.

    //Con esta sentencia se evita que el contenedor tenga valores height y width nulos.
    viewRoot.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    //Se asigna un tamaño a la vista contenedora
    viewRoot.layout(0, 0, viewRoot.getMeasuredWidth(), viewRoot.getMeasuredHeight());
    //Se crea el bitmap
    final Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(viewRoot.getMeasuredWidth(),
                viewRoot.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    //Renderiza la vista del contenedor
    viewRoot.draw(c);
```

**El objeto bitmap es el contenedor de la imagen final**
Con esto basta para convertir cualquier diseño de vistas por complejo que sea, en una imagen.

Referencia(en ingles): 
http://android-crap.blogspot.mx/2013/02/create-bitmap-from-layoutview.html